# Macbook Pro 2013 boot weird issue

Tags: boot, mac, macbook

**My macbook doesn't want to boot properly** - after I hit restart or turn off & on I see Apple logo appearing and I hear a chime, then progress bar appears and **computer usually freezes for about 1 minute or so and reboots many times**. It usually takes 30-50 minutes of such behavior for it to finally start.

**After that computer is fully usable & stable.** Even gaming is totally possible and I can run it for weeks without restart. Rock stable.
Absolutely nothing when reading / saving to disk (checked up to 70%) of capacity.

**I checked the disk's SMART - not errors** (reallocated sectors count was 100). Used 'smartctl' for that.

**Main battery is almost new** (less than 50 cycles - holds for hours).

This happens regardless whether the computer is connected to power or runs on battery.

I tried even creating a boot flash drive with MacOs installer. When I hit 'option' key when I hear the chime after a moment I see the menu to choose boot drive but sometimes it freezes so I can't even choose the boot device or a moment after I select one.
Basically I'm unable to boot any other OS on the computer (well - maybe I could but I'm not patient enough to repeat this dozens times)...

**Computer doesn't overheat or anything.**

I'm a tech & hardware savvy guy but this boggles my mind... **is there something going wrong with the ram or the mainboard** ?? I see no other explanation at this point...

**If so then how do I verify this ?**

----- UPDATE ------

My disk is a regular SSD drive.

Smart Status:

```
smartctl 7.4 2023-08-01 r5530 [Darwin 20.6.0 x86_64] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-23, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Model Family:     Apple SD/SM/TS...E/F/G SSDs
Device Model:     APPLE SSD SM0128F
Serial Number:    S1K3NYBG157365
LU WWN Device Id: 5 002538 655584d30
Firmware Version: UXM2JA1Q
User Capacity:    121 332 826 112 bytes [121 GB]
Sector Sizes:     512 bytes logical, 4096 bytes physical
Rotation Rate:    Solid State Device
TRIM Command:     Available
Device is:        In smartctl database 7.3/5528
ATA Version is:   ATA8-ACS T13/1699-D revision 4c
SATA Version is:  SATA 3.0, 6.0 Gb/s (current: 6.0 Gb/s)
Local Time is:    Wed Feb 21 22:32:07 2024 CET
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED

General SMART Values:
Offline data collection status:  (0x00) Offline data collection activity
                    was never started.
                    Auto Offline Data Collection: Disabled.
Self-test execution status:      (   0) The previous self-test routine completed
                    without error or no self-test has ever 
                    been run.
Total time to complete Offline 
data collection:        (    0) seconds.
Offline data collection
capabilities:            (0x5f) SMART execute Offline immediate.
                    Auto Offline data collection on/off support.
                    Abort Offline collection upon new
                    command.
                    Offline surface scan supported.
                    Self-test supported.
                    No Conveyance Self-test supported.
                    Selective Self-test supported.
SMART capabilities:            (0x0003) Saves SMART data before entering
                    power-saving mode.
                    Supports SMART auto save timer.
Error logging capability:        (0x01) Error logging supported.
                    General Purpose Logging supported.
Short self-test routine 
recommended polling time:    (   2) minutes.
Extended self-test routine
recommended polling time:    (  10) minutes.

SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 40
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     0x001a   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0033   100   100   000    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0032   097   097   000    Old_age   Always       -       14242
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   031   031   000    Old_age   Always       -       69216
169 Unknown_Apple_Attrib    0x0013   253   253   010    Pre-fail  Always       -       1009489282944
173 Wear_Leveling_Count     0x0032   168   168   100    Old_age   Always       -       3320074077022
174 Host_Reads_MiB          0x0022   099   099   000    Old_age   Always       -       41761352
175 Host_Writes_MiB         0x0022   099   099   000    Old_age   Always       -       35964924
192 Power-Off_Retract_Count 0x0012   099   099   000    Old_age   Always       -       451
194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0022   063   063   000    Old_age   Always       -       37 (Min/Max 7/65)
197 Current_Pending_Sector  0x0022   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    0x001a   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
240 Unknown_SSD_Attribute   0x0022   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0

SMART Error Log Version: 1
No Errors Logged

SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
Num  Test_Description    Status                  Remaining  LifeTime(hours)  LBA_of_first_error
# 1  Short offline       Completed without error       00%         0         -
# 2  Short offline       Aborted by host               00%         0         -
# 3  Short offline       Aborted by host               00%         0         -
# 4  Short offline       Aborted by host               00%         0         -
# 5  Short offline       Aborted by host               00%         0         -
# 6  Short offline       Aborted by host               00%         0         -
# 7  Short offline       Aborted by host               00%         0         -
# 8  Short offline       Aborted by host               00%         0         -
# 9  Short offline       Aborted by host               00%         0         -
#10  Short offline       Aborted by host               00%         0         -
#11  Short offline       Aborted by host               00%         0         -
#12  Short offline       Aborted by host               00%         0         -
#13  Short offline       Aborted by host               00%         0         -
#14  Short offline       Aborted by host               00%         0         -
#15  Short offline       Aborted by host               00%         0         -
#16  Short offline       Aborted by host               00%         0         -
#17  Short offline       Aborted by host               00%         0         -
#18  Short offline       Aborted by host               00%         0         -
#19  Short offline       Aborted by host               00%         0         -
#20  Short offline       Aborted by host               00%         0         -
#21  Short offline       Aborted by host               00%         0         -

SMART Selective self-test log data structure revision number 1
 SPAN  MIN_LBA  MAX_LBA  CURRENT_TEST_STATUS
    1        0        0  Not_testing
    2        0        0  Not_testing
    3        0        0  Not_testing
    4        0        0  Not_testing
    5        0        0  Not_testing
Selective self-test flags (0x0):
  After scanning selected spans, do NOT read-scan remainder of disk.
If Selective self-test is pending on power-up, resume after 0 minute delay.

The above only provides legacy SMART information - try 'smartctl -x' for more
```

----- UPDATE #2 ------

Computer won't let me into diagnostics nor recovery mode. It freezes almost instantly - see pictures. Can't even move mouse pointer.

Sorry for dusty screen - these new phones won't miss anything ;)

Diagnostics mode:
[image]

Recovery mode (tried normal & internet) - both fail.
[image]

Comment: Have you run Apple's [hardware diags](https://support.apple.com/en-us/102550)? Is your internal boot device an HDD? If so, use a SMART tool to give us all the sector-related counter values (at least these four: Reallocated Sectors Count; Reported Uncorrectable Errors; Current Pending Sector Count; Uncorrectable Sector Count)? In general, if an HDD is showing nonzero values in any of the sector-problem counters, then it is dying and the failures will only snowball from here. It's time to replace the drive. Failing sectors cause slow read retries that can cause extremely long hangs and slowness.

Comment: Thanks for the comment - I added a SMART info.

Comment: Since it's an SSD most of what I wrote doesn't apply. Did you run Apple's hardware diags yet?

Comment: Well - I finally tried - however computer freezes almost instantly after I see the wifi network selection, sometimes I can select it but freezes on typing in the password. And sometimes if I don't touch anything it will "work" until I try to select network. Same thing happens with recovery mode (local or internet) - spinning globe appears and it freezes after 1-4 seconds. I will try to disconnect wifi module (if that's even possible) and see whether this makes any difference.

Comment: This is almost certainly a hardware issue of some sort. Time to take it in for repair. Or just thank it for a decade of faithful service and recycle it.

Comment: I'm sure it's hardware but since I'm kind-of-a-geek then will try to diagnose it and repair if possible. if I don't think of anything then will sell it for parts - better that than recycle - at least someone will get a chance at repairing their computer.